# Birt report duplicating rows - Table

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, report, birt

Im having duplicate rows in a table like the printscreen[image: duplication rows in the report]

I read the solution was selecting the columns and check the option: "supress duplicates"  (as printscreen) but this is not working as well.

Does anybody has an ideia of how to fix this problem?  Thanks in advance
[image: supress duplicates - eclipse]

Comment: I don't know what this is, but I don't think it's duplicate (maybe extra empty rows?).

Answer (score 1):

In BIRT, Suppress Duplicates just makes sure the value in the column in not repeated and hence you could see Blank or rows with no values.
And the other reason why we get multiple rows is because there are those many rows with same values.

To avoid blank rows we can make use of hide condition. Steps for the same:

1. Select the detail row of the table:
   [Detail Row Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOQqI.png)
2. In Property Editor -> Properties -> Visibility -> check on Hide Element and add 
   hidden condition in the pop up window
    [Row Visibility condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOQqI.png)
3. Visibility condition could be like this :

   if(row["Col1"]=="" && row["Col2"]=="" && row["Col3"]==""){true}

If "" doesn't work in the condition, replace it with null

Hope this works.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting duplicate rows in your table, where it looks like all the values are identical. You probably have one of these issues

1. A join to a second data set that causes a second row of data to be created, where the filed with two values is not displayed on your report table.  = If that field is not required remove it from your dataset.
2. There are duplicate rows of data in your raw data source = use something like 'select distinct/unique' in your SQL to return only a single row.
3. If you only have a single data source with only unique rows, what you are displaying may not show a field with two distinct values, but the table is bound to the data that does have two values.  Suppress dupes is not going to work because there are not any dupes. = Either display the field with multiple values or clean up your data pull so there is no longer duplicates where they are not intended.